# Distributed algorithm for Minimum-Weight Spanning Trees

Tags: java, distributed-computing

Does anyone know if there is available somewhere a Java implementation of the Gallagher-Humblet-Spira (GHS) algorithm?

Comment: Instead of downvoting a good question - how about helping him fix it?

Comment: I've found a python implementation. https://github.com/francesco-bongiovanni/Distributed-Graph-Algorithms/tree/master/Minimum-Spanning-Tree

Also I am working on a C++ implementation.

Comment: Done with the implementation: https://github.com/atuljangra/Distributed-Graph-Algorithms